# Wordpress with a lot of user accounts

Tags: wordpress

I'm programming a Wordpress website, and I would like to know if there are any problems if many users register, for example 100,000 ?

I don't know if Wordpress is adapted for this kind of use.

( I have to import a list of more than 100,000 user accounts, from another website. )

Comment: users are just some records in the db. unless your db is highly space constrained, go for it. question it: will you have 100,000 users pounding on WP at the same time?

Comment: As @Marc B sad, they are only records in `wp_users` and `wp_user_meta` tables.

Comment: Thanks guys, indeed, there's no chance I have 100,000 users at the same time. This is a perfect answer for a weird question. 
I must stop underestimated Worpress!